# Unable to enable TLS on LDAP Server

Tags: ldap, openldap

I would like to enable Secure LDAP authentication on my CentOS 7.2 Samba server... however I am getting stuck setting up TLS on the LDAP server itself.

**EDIT: [** I installed openldap from the default repositories **]**

I am currently following the tutorial [here](http://boredwookie.net/index.php/blog/configure-centos-7-and-openldap-secure-connections/) but instead of entering settings manually into the configuration files, I am trying to do it the "proper" way and use ldapmodify.  It took me a while to understand how to use the tool, but I have finally mastered that part.  I get stuck however on the following.

**Command:**

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f TLS.conifg -v
```

using the above command to install the following LDIF file I get the below error.

**TLS.config:**

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/file.server.org.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/file.server.org.key.pem
```

**Error:**

```
Entry (olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config), attribute 'olcTLSCipherSuite' not allowed
```

**EDIT2: [** I have both openSSL and gnuTLS installed so I fulfill the requirements for TLS as specified by the openLDAP documentation found [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/install.html) **]**

**EDIT3: [** I have my Certificates in the correct folder with what I can only guess to be the correct permissions as shown below.

[image]

**]**

**EDIT4: Resolution**

As mentioned by 84104 below, the olcTLS configuration directives are addressed in the `cn=config` file and not in the database definitions themselves.

I have succeeded in configuring the TLS directives and have moved on to creating my entries.

Thank your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `olcTLS*` attributes are applied to `cn=config`, the general server config, not any specific database, e.g. `olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config`.

```
$ ldapsearch -b cn=config '(|(olcTLSCertificateFile=*)(olcTLSCertificateKeyFile=*)(olcTLSCipherSuite=*))' olcTLSCertificateFile olcTLSCertificateKeyFile olcTLSCipherSuite olcTLSProtocolMin
dn: cn=config
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/ssl/ldap.cert
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/ssl/ldap.key
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH:!aNull:!MD5:@STRENGTH
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.1
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually found the answer yesturday, about 3 hours after my last edit.  I but didn't have enough time to make an update.  It seems the guide I was using was incorrect.